# Unexpected effect of Holo Light Theme of my action bar

Tags: android

I have used XML to define the Theme of the action bar for my Main activity to be as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />

<style name="HomeTheme" 
    parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/HomeActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

 <style name="HomeActionBarStyle" 
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>
```

Then in my Manifest file I have set the Theme of my activity with the defined Theme :

```
<activity
....
android:theme="@style/HomeTheme"
....
</activity>
```

everything went file as expected except two thing:
1) the border line of the action bar area is still blue 
2) the background color of the action bar area is white not grey.

I am not sure what could be my mistake or this is just a bug in my emulator?
I need to solve the previous two points just to have beautiful GUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

`parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar"`

to

`parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid"`

By default the standard ActionBar has the blue line under it instead of the gray. The solid variant is probably what you're looking for.